# How do I get the "5 routes" achievement?

Tags: ticket-to-ride, online

What is meant in the poker player of using all "5" routes - is it all routes that use 5 carriages or tickets that score 5 points? I did the former but didn't get the achievement.

Comment: this question is not about ticket-to-ride, is it about an online version?

Comment: It sounds like you are talking about a computer version of the game. Although Such questions can be in scope, this particular question deals only specifically with the computer version, and is of no meaning or help with the non-computer version. Voted to close.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Get all the 5-car, 10 point scores, there are 8. You must also win the game too. Recommend playing against only one bot.

Answer (score -1):

It needs to be in the standard version. I tried with the 1910 version and it didn't work.

Comment: Hello user6863! You should add comments as comments to the answer/question as appropriate rather than adding a comment as a new answer. It's best if answers stand by themselves :)